# How to implement SIS Thresholding in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

In Aforge.net I saw one thresholding named SIS (Simple Image Statistics) Thresholding. How can I implement the same thresholding in opencv python? A link is provided in the comments.

Comment: Please give much more information. We do not know what SIS means and how it relates to thresholding. Please provide a reference link. Also read how to ask a proper question on this forum.

Comment: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/39e861e0-e4bb-7e09-c067-6cbda5d646f3.htm. Please go thru the link .
I want to do same thresholding in opencv . I couldn't find any specific function.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know OpenCV that well. But this is how I would do it in ImageMagick 7 command line on Bash Unix.

IM 7 (HDRI default) with clamp=off is needed, to avoid the clipping of the convolution for values outside the quantum range (that would happen for non-HDRI).

I note that -scale 1x1! will compute the average, not the sum. But since both numerator and denominator have the same number of pixels, the ratio will not matter whether I sum or average.

Input:

[image]

```
wt=`magick sample11.png \
\( -clone 0 -define convolve:scale=! -define compose:clamp=off -morphology convolve "3x1: -1,0,1" +duplicate -compose multiply -composite -evaluate pow 0.5 \) \
\( -clone 0 -define convolve:scale=! -define compose:clamp=off -morphology convolve "1x3: -1,0,1" +duplicate -compose multiply -composite -evaluate pow 0.5 \) \
-delete 0 -evaluate-sequence max \
-scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:u]" info:`

wtI=`magick sample11.png \
\( -clone 0 -define convolve:scale=! -define compose:clamp=off -morphology convolve "3x1: -1,0,1" +duplicate -compose multiply -composite -evaluate pow 0.5 \) \
\( -clone 0 -define convolve:scale=! -define compose:clamp=off -morphology convolve "1x3: -1,0,1" +duplicate -compose multiply -composite -evaluate pow 0.5 \) \
\( -clone 1,2 -evaluate-sequence max \) \
-delete 1,2 \
-evaluate-sequence multiply \
-scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:u]" info:`

thresh=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:100*$wtI/$wt]" info:`
echo $thresh
50.0114

magick sample11.png -threshold $thresh% result.png
```

[image]

Here are some useful links for doing the convolution, difference, absolute value, multiply and mean(average) in Python OpenCV:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/25/convolutions-with-opencv-and-python/

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html

However, I do not think it does a very good job on real images. I tried on a few. Here is one example:

[image]

and here is the result:

[image]

So I question what the goal of this thresholding is or what types of images does it do well on?